# Answer to question put on hold

Tags: discussion

My question is : Is there a way to provide answer to OP, even when the question is put on hold?
Here's a recent question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719704/sort-names-bubble-sort-c
. I tried working out a solution to the problem and solved it. When I went back to post it as an answer, the question was already put on hold. Is there a way I can tell give my answer to the OP?
Note : There is also an answer to the question, which does not solve the problem in its entirety, as I discovered that there are more modifications required.

Comment: You can propose an edit to the answer, but bear in mind that the question was put on-hold because *it isn't a good question*! Encourage the OP to improve it and get it reopened, then you can post your answer, the OP can get some rep. back and everyone's happy!

Comment: That question was closed for a reason: to prevent answers from being posted and to encourage the questioner to improve it. Insisting on answering closed questions is detrimental to the community and, in the long term, to the questioner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to add a new answer to that question *while it is still on hold*. However, there are still three options if you want to give the OP an answer (in ascending order of how good an idea I think they are):

1. **Add a comment** providing the answer. However, this is not possible with < 50 reputation (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) and will not allow much to be posted (only the shortest of code snippets are readable, for example). Also, comments do not get the audit trail and reputation of an actual answer; this is not encouraged.
2. **Propose an edit** to the existing answer, adding the additional information you think is required. This means that the OP gets their answer, but you only get +2 rep for the accepted edit and the question stays downvoted and on hold.
3. **Help improve the question**, either by proposing edits or encouraging the OP to read and follow the appropriate help documentation. This is the best way, in my opinion, because, as well as the direct improvement to that question, it hopefully has a knock-on effect for the OP's future contributions. We get a better question, the OP gets some reputation back and you get to post an answer; everyone wins!

Note that questions generally get put on hold for good reasons, *because they aren't good questions*, so trying to get around this by commenting/editing existing answers subverts the purpose of the site. It's much better to help the OP to improve their question. Also, I think that giving an answer to a bad question reinforces poor behaviour, but that's a whole separate discussion!

Comment: Thanks! I have suggested a possible edit to the question. It is in review process now.

Comment: @AyushiJha that edit (although definitely an improvement) still does not take the question to a state where it should be reopened. The OP should read the Help Center article linked in the close reason, and update their question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! So now it's the OP's responsibility. And I got 4 downvotes. :(

Comment: @AyushiJha Meta votes don't count towards your rep - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: thanks, I am bookmarking the Help Center link now :)

Comment: @AyushiJha The downvotes probably happened because, at a glance, it looked like you were saying "we should answer anyone no matter if the question is bad". To be fair, you were NOT asking that, but the subject is tackled enough here that it's possible other users' minds just went there. It's nice to see you took a completely different approach and are opened to learning the site :). Welcome to Stack ^^

Comment: Honestly, I feel strongly that an answer that was started BEFORE a question was put on-hold should be allowed. I've spent considerable amount of time writing up answers to questions on several occasions that went wasted because a question was put on hold RIGHT before I posted my answer.

Comment: @AnonymousSB there is a grace period. But if you find that's happening a lot I'd recommend being more selective about the kinds of question you're investing time in.

Comment: That seems like a bad choice to make. Users need help, and most times I witness on-hold being applied to users with poor English, which just seems discriminatory.

Comment: @AnonymousSB if the only problem with the question is poor language, that can be fixed through editing. Often that's *not* the only problem.