# Behaviour when a question is put on hold while you are answering it

Tags: feature-request, on-hold

I was reading a brand new question that had some issues, such as lacking a working example code, and needed to be properly edited. But, despite that, I was able to identify the problem and started writing an answer with some code to illustrate why his code was failing at run time.

When it was all ready and I clicked the button to submit my answer, I was notified that the question had been put on hold and my text could not be posted. Another user, however, had written a short and speculative answer that was successfully submitted because he finished it before the question was put on hold. Basically, it went like this:

1. Question was posted
2. User A started writing an answer
3. User B started writing an answer
4. User A finishes his text and successfully submits it
5. The question is put on hold
6. User B finishes his text and is unable to submit it

I understand there are [other things that can be done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286883/5302415), but I propose, considering my limited experience, that user B should have some capability to post his answer (e.g for some time after the question is put on hold ). My reasoning is that the way things are now favours short and not so well crafted answers instead of more complete and elaborate ones that require more time( not necessarily longer ones).

Additionally( or alternatively), one should also be notified that the question is going to be put on hold so he could either avoid investing his time in an answer ( and invest it in an edit or another question, for example) or quickly finish what he had in mind, if time allows it.

For reference, here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798579/cout-gives-segmentation-fault-c)

Comment: AFAIK this feature is already implemented: [This answer was posted *after* the question was closed, how is that possible?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå as I understand it the client-side interface will block you from posting after the question is closed, so you can only post if that check somehow fails (and you are within whatever grace period is defined server side).

Comment: @josilber Ah, okay, let me rephrase that: *"partially implemented"* ;)

Comment: Questions that get closed are mostly of the kind that aren't worth answering at all (or only after a thorough edit). Over time, you'll learn to spot those kinds of questions so you can avoid answering them (or start editing them first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your first proposal (allowing answers shortly after a question is marked as off topic), I don't think this is a good idea because it encourages users to answer off-topic questions, which they shouldn't do (see e.g. [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) and [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)).

Regarding your second proposal (being notified when a question is about to be put on hold), you will be able to view close vote counts on others' questions once you have 3,000 reputation. As @rene points out, you might get a pretty good sense that a question is about to be put on hold if the question is quickly attracting downvotes or users are leaving and upvoting comments about how the question is off-topic.

Comment: Don't forget to mention for the second proposal that question score is also a good indicator, specially on new questions, as are a flood of comments....

Comment: About the question score, the specific question I was referring to had a positive score of 1 as of now( still on hold). The comments are a bit better indicators, but still subjective. I've added the question at hand in mine so people can check for themselves. So I agree with you about the first proposal, but not on the second one. If you have 3000 reputation. you probably already have enough experience not to need to use the feature I am proposing.

Comment: @guivenca Thanks for providing the question link. In this case the very first (and most highly upvoted) comment could have hinted to you that it was probably going to be closed -- debugging questions on Stack Overflow require a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE); if you every find yourself debugging a question that you can't reproduce with code from the question, it's likely off topic. Pointers about the sorts of questions that are off-topic for Stack Overflow can be found [in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for all the links and clarifications. At the time, there weren't many comments or votes to rely on and I guess I was too eager to help and did not stop to think if I should. Specially because I had made a similar mistake once so the answer was clear to me without an MVCE. But now I see that's no reason not to demand one.